# jquery validator to avoid some word include in a sentence

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

With Jquery Validation, I have a form 
Now that I want to check a field that cannot contain some specific word. Like

- Field doesn't have the words 'Pte. Ltd.' in the string - return valid
- Field has the words 'Pte. Ltd.' in the string - return invalid

Here is my script function with jquery validation witch doesn't work.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("contains",
        function (value, element, param) {
            var contains  = false;
            for (i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
                if (value.includes(param[i])) {
                    contains  = true;
                }
            }
        return this.optional(element) || contains;
    },"Cannot include Ptd. Ltd.");
```

under rules of jquery validation

```
            rules: {
                companyname: {
                    required: true,
                    contains: ["Pte. Ltd.", "Private Limited"],
                },
```

Comment: The way you have it setup now, only the very last item in your loop is used.  Each time through the loop, the previous value of `contains` is overwritten.  Also the boolean is backwards.  `true` means valid and `false` means invalid.  See the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to swap the true/false statements, since `true` means that it passed the validation and is valid. You can also reformat it to make it a little more efficient. There's no need to loop through every param after an invalid one has been identified:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("contains",
  function (value, element, param) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
      return true;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
      if (value.includes(param[i])) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  },
  "Cannot include Ptd. Ltd."
);
```

If the validation isn't running at all for the input element you want validated, make sure the element has the `companyname` name, per your rule definition.